# Massive follower and following lists

Tags: algorithm, relational-database

I have a fruit fly database that is nearly identical to a follower/followee situation. I understand how to implement the solution via tables in a relational DBMS.  However, the magnitude of the problem is daunting and exceeds what could reasonably be achieved.  That is, I have 10^6 fruit flies and 10^7 attributes.  There are a few constraints, but I would still be looking at a truly massive table -- something approaching 10^11 records.

What non-relational DBMS algorithms might be appropriate?

Comment: What do you want to do do with this data?

Comment: You need to provide more information on the data and the operations.  10,000,000 attributes seems like a lot -- unless you mean 10 attributes per fruit fly.  Relational databases can easily handle a million records with ten attributes each.

Comment: You want to group flies to their followees and select some of them or count them? In memory?

Comment: This is a many-to-many mapping that is virtually identical to a follower-followee problem in a social network.  That is, each fly can have an unlimited number of attributes, and each attribute can be associated with an unlimited number of flies.